# How to add additional tabs to user profiles

Tags: 7, routes, users

I'm trying to find a way to add another tab to the tabbed menu under each user's username on the user/* page.

I want to have View, Edit, and an additional link. I'm not sure where I need to be looking in the code to edit this menu and I can't find any documentation thus far. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can implement [`hook_menu`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in a custom module and use `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` as the type, and the path needs to start with `user/`

```
function HOOK_menu() {
  $items['user/mypage'] = array(
    'title' => t('My Tab'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    //'page callback' => 'mymodule_mypage', //mymodule_mypage should be a function that returns HTML for the content area
    //'page arguments' => array(0, 1, 2), // 0 is arg(0), 1 is arg(1) etc...
  );
  return $items;
}
```

For all the array elements see [this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

Comment: where would this code go?

Comment: This code goes in a custom module. Check [this page](http://drupal.org/node/361112) for a guide on how to write custom modules. In this case however you'll need the most basic module, you need only 2 files a .info and a .module file. The .module file will contain the above code, but the `HOOK_` needs to be replaced by the module's name. For example: If `mycustommodule` was your custom module name the function name would be `mycustommodule_menu()`

Comment: When you say "//mymodule_mypage should be a function that returns HTML for the content area" what do you mean?

Comment: Any function name that you put in `page callback` will be called when the path `user/mypage` is requested. You can create a new function which returns markup, or use a drupal function such as `drupal_get_form` etc.